# Flutter phone authentication with the Play Integrity API

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

Flutter phone authentication is not working since the safety net device verification is deprecated.

For the new projects created after January 2023, the safety net option is not available. We must use the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview).

I enabled the Play Integrity API from a Firebase project.

Linked Firebase project as suggested in *[Get started using App Check with Play Integrity on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider)*.

I enabled *Play Integrity* from Flutter code as suggested in *[Get started using App Check in Flutter apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers)*.

Still it’s redirecting to a browser page, asking us to verify the app with [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA).

On the browser page im getting this error:

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared.

When I press back, I'm getting 'Missing client identifier error':

[![Enter image description here][5]][5]

[image]

Nothing I have mentioned helped me fix the error messages. Is there a way?